# Starting dynamic simple_one_for_one workers after supervisor starts

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I have a named `Supervisor` that supervises many `simple_one_for_one` workers, which perform a task at regular intervals for each user on my system.

I want the app to start one worker for each user when the `Supervisor` starts for the first time, and I want the app to do the same if the `Supervisor` restarts at a later date, for whatever reason.

At the moment I start all the children dynamically in the `Application`'s `start(type, args)` callback, but if the `Supervisor` is restarted, that won't start all the child processes.

How do I ensure all the dynamic child workers are started immediately after the `Supervisor` starts/restart, at any time?

(My app is in Elixir, but the same principles apply to Erlang.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way I've done this that works pretty well is to use another supervisor and a "restart worker". Your supervisor is a child of the new one -- it's a sibling of the restart worker. The new supervisor uses `one_for_all` or `rest_for_one`, so that if your supervisor dies, the restart worker is *also* restarted.

When the restart worker is restarted, it can start the dynamic workers.

Comment: Cool this is exactly what I wanted :-). Any insight on when I would want "rest_for_one" instead of "one_for_all" though?